# I have the following Swift 3 code to find center the current location using MapKit and CoreLocation but it is not working. What did I do wrong?

Tags: xcode, swift3, macos-sierra

The following is a code snippet from the ViewController.swift file inside my Swift 3 project.  What should I change to make it work or could you give any pointers?  Do you know why it is not working and instead, going to some arbritrary location instead of my location after the notification for the current location is done?

```
import Cocoa
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: NSViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate , MKMapViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var STAVO_map: MKMapView!
    var manager: CLLocationManager!
    var currentLocation : CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CLLocationManager()

        STAVO_map.delegate = self
        STAVO_map.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }


    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
        self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 500, 500)
        self.STAVO_map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things things, first I would change didUpdateLocations to

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last as! CLLocation
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 1000, 1000)


    self.STAVO_map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

In viewDidLoad…startUpdatingLocation is an async function so you’re always going to get noLocation set until didUpdateLocations is called. I would remove the 3 lines where you set noLocation, the viewRegion and setRegion. You shouldn’t need to call startUpdatingLocation twice so you can remove the second call (besides, viewDidLoad runs in main queue by default so no need for DispatchQueue)

Comment: Also, in case you're using simulator to test this, the location value is set via the debug menu (Debug-> location)

Comment: What do you mean by didUpdateLocations func? There is only viewDidLoad and locationManager.  Also, where do I add or change the twos lines you requested.

Comment: It's the locationManager function, I just referred to it by the delegate method name. The 2 lines should replace the 'let center' and 'let region' statements.

Comment: I made the changes requested but it still centers about the USA now.  Any other tips?

Comment: Are you running this using Xcode? If so, add a print statement inside the locationManager function. When you run it, do you see the print statement in the console output?

Comment: You could also post your project somewhere and I can clone it to debug.